why dotnet restore failed but downloaded the correct version of library: with Error NU1403
donet restore failed due to error NU1403: Package content hash validation failed for OpenTelemetry.1.8.1..
I went to the .nuget\packages folder and deleted the existing OpenTelemetry libaray, and then ran dotnet restore again but it still failed and it downloaded the OpenTelemetry 1.8.1 library for me in the folder. I was able to run dotnet restore --evaluate-force to solve the issue. My question is why it downloaded the target library with correct version but still complained the package content hash number was not correct? Does that mean the source library was updated after last dotnet restore so it generated a new hash number, and the hash number for this library in the local packages.lock.json file needs to be updated accordingly?
